# Drawing a line with DirectX C#

Tags: c#, directx-9

I'm trying to draw a simple line using DirectX9 and encountered the following:

When the code reach the line:

```
Device device = new Device( some example code I'v found);
```

The location of the form is changing in a periodic manner, meaning every time the program executes. I see (in debug mode) that the form location properties change and return to their original values on the 6th execution.  Why?

Upon resizing the code throw a general exception pointing to the line

```
device.DrawUserPrimitive(..)
```

Comment: If you're using C# you really should look at XNA. It's a wrapper for DirectX with C# that makes things WAY easier.

Comment: What library are you using to call DirectX?  e.g. http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/